# Insert corresponding columns into larger table in SQL

Tags: sql, insert

Let's say I have an empty table with 5 columns and a large number of tables with a random selection of those 5 columns. How can I insert the columns that are present in smaller tables into the corresponding columns in the large table?

For Example:

Table A has columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Table B has columns 1, 2, 5

I want to insert the values of table B into the corresponding columns of A, and leave columns 3 and 4 in A as NULL.

I know this is not a good way to use SQL, don't ask how I got into this mess!

I have tried:

```
CASE WHEN COL_LENGTH('MyTable', 'MyColumn') IS NOT NULL THEN MyColumn ELSE NULL END
```

but I get an error "Invalid column name", even though SQL doesn't have to use the (non-existant) column.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tag your database platform. It sounds like flaw in the design somewhere ;-) You will probably need dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

List the columns when you `insert`:

```
insert into a (col1, col2, col5)
   select col1, col2, col5
   from b;
```

Assuming that `col3` and `col4` allow `NULL` values and have no `DEFAULT` (or the default is `NULL`), then these are populated with `NULL` values for all rows inserted by the statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, the question wasn't clear enough. I want one piece of code that works for any amount of columns present in table B, so for example if B had columns 2, 4, 5 or columns 1, 4 or even just column 2. There are loads of these tables that I want to use to populate the main table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize dynamic SQL. With the below script, you dynamically get the parameter list from the system table where columns from table A match table B. Then you build your dynamic SQL statement and execute it.

The code below currently will PRINT the SQL statement; however, once you are satisfied, you can comment out the PRINT(@SQL) and comment back in the EXECUTE(@SQL)

```
DECLARE @TableAName VARCHAR(100)
        ,@TableBName VARCHAR(100);

SET @TableAName = 'TableA';
SET @TableBName = 'TableB';

DECLARE @Parameter VARCHAR(1000) = ''
        ,@SQL VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@TBLASchema VARCHAR(100)
        ,@TBLBSchema VARCHAR(100)
        ,@DatabaseName VARCHAR(100);

SET @TBLASchema = (SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(T.object_id)
                   FROM sys.tables AS T
                   WHERE T.name = @TableAName);

SET @TBLBSchema = (SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(T.object_id)
                   FROM sys.tables AS T
                   WHERE T.name = @TableBName);

SET @DatabaseName = DB_NAME();

SELECT @Parameter = @Parameter + ',[' + TBL_COLS.name + ']'
FROM sys.tables AS T
JOIN sys.columns AS TBL_COLS
    ON T.[object_id] = TBL_COLS.[object_id]
    AND T.name = @TableAName
WHERE TBL_COLS.name IN (SELECT TBL2_COLS.name
                        FROM sys.tables AS T
                        JOIN sys.columns AS TBL2_COLS
                            ON T.[object_id] = TBL2_COLS.[object_id]
                            AND T.name = @TableBName);

SET @Parameter = SUBSTRING(@Parameter,2,LEN(@Parameter)-1);

SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO [' + @DatabaseName + '].[' + @TBLASchema + '].[' + @TableAName + '] ' 
           + '(' + @Parameter + ')'
           + ' SELECT ' + @Parameter
           + ' FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].[' + @TBLBSchema + '].[' + @TableBName + '];'

PRINT(@SQL);
--EXECUTE(@SQL);
```